# Two different errors before handshake in isolated nodes

Tags: daemon

I have a personal node and a node on an EC2. The personal node keeps giving me the following error when I run the daemon.

```
2022-03-26 14:07:08.618 I No available peer in white list filtered by 1
2022-03-26 14:07:08.618 I No available peer in gray list filtered by 1
2022-03-26 14:07:08.618 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] [0] state: closed in state before_handshake
2022-03-26 14:07:08.619 I [3.86.2.59:15668 4700553a-3cb1-417c-86a7-118164e215ec OUT] CLOSE CONNECTION
2022-03-26 14:07:09.619 I Failed to connect to any, trying seeds
2022-03-26 14:07:09.628 I 0Connect failed to 107.20.71.167:15688
2022-03-26 14:07:09.637 I [3.86.2.59:15668 ef5d09b1-9575-41a6-b8d8-74494be21ba2 OUT] NEW CONNECTION
2022-03-26 14:07:09.637 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] 243 bytes sent for category command-1001 initiated by us
2022-03-26 14:07:09.647 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] 10 bytes received for category command-1007 initiated by peer
2022-03-26 14:07:09.647 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] 29 bytes sent for category command-1007 initiated by peer
2022-03-26 14:07:09.654 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] 317 bytes received for category command-1001 initiated by us
2022-03-26 14:07:09.654 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] [0] state: closed in state before_handshake
2022-03-26 14:07:09.654 I [3.86.2.59:15668 ef5d09b1-9575-41a6-b8d8-74494be21ba2 OUT] CLOSE CONNECTION
```

Or

```
2022-03-26 15:00:20.788 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] [0] state: closed in state before_handshake
2022-03-26 15:00:20.788 I [3.86.2.59:15668 3cd09087-95db-4460-8f15-fc71809ae4c6 OUT] CLOSE CONNECTION
2022-03-26 15:00:21.788 I No available peer in gray list filtered by 1
2022-03-26 15:00:22.788 I Failed to connect to any, trying seeds
2022-03-26 15:00:22.798 I 0Connect failed to 107.20.71.167:15688
2022-03-26 15:00:22.807 I [3.86.2.59:15668 746cb225-944f-4e48-bb3c-429dcc54a32c OUT] NEW CONNECTION
2022-03-26 15:00:22.808 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] 243 bytes sent for category command-1001 initiated by us
2022-03-26 15:00:22.820 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] 10 bytes received for category command-1007 initiated by peer
2022-03-26 15:00:22.820 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] 29 bytes sent for category command-1007 initiated by peer
2022-03-26 15:00:22.830 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] 317 bytes received for category command-1001 initiated by us
2022-03-26 15:00:22.830 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] 247 bytes received for category command-2006 initiated by peer
2022-03-26 15:00:22.830 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] Received NOTIFY_REQUEST_CHAIN (7 blocks
2022-03-26 15:00:22.830 E [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] Requested chain before handshake, dropping connection
2022-03-26 15:00:22.830 E Setting timer on a shut down object
```

The EC2 gives me a different error when I run the daemon.

```
2022-03-26 13:55:38.006 I [3.86.2.59:15668 666519dd-2369-441b-bec8-ed9443602a22 OUT] NEW CONNECTION
2022-03-26 13:55:38.006 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] 243 bytes sent for category command-1001 initiated by us
2022-03-26 13:55:38.006 I [3.86.2.59:45350 7765e728-104a-4ca0-92a8-14ab462d8ee3 INC] NEW CONNECTION
2022-03-26 13:55:38.007 I [3.86.2.59:45350 INC] 243 bytes received for category command-1001 initiated by peer
2022-03-26 13:55:38.007 I [3.86.2.59:45350 INC] 229 bytes sent for category command-1001 initiated by peer
2022-03-26 13:55:38.007 I [3.86.2.59:45350 INC] [0] state: closed in state before_handshake
2022-03-26 13:55:38.007 I [3.86.2.59:45350 7765e728-104a-4ca0-92a8-14ab462d8ee3 INC] CLOSE CONNECTION
2022-03-26 13:55:38.007 I Failed to invoke command 1001 return code -3
2022-03-26 13:55:38.007 W [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-3, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_DESTROYED)
2022-03-26 13:55:38.007 I [3.86.2.59:15668 OUT] [0] state: closed in state before_handshake
2022-03-26 13:55:38.007 I [3.86.2.59:15668 666519dd-2369-441b-bec8-ed9443602a22 OUT] CLOSE CONNECTION
2022-03-26 13:55:39.008 I No available peer in white list filtered by 1
2022-03-26 13:55:39.133 I [107.20.71.167:15668 OUT] [0] state: closed in state normal
2022-03-26 13:55:39.133 I [107.20.71.167:15668 87aaae7e-bffa-4563-8dce-0decdb56132b OUT] CLOSE CONNECTION
```

I was trying out a thing to see if I could set up a mini network. But it isn't working even though I changed the ports and opened them. Is this a hopeless experiment? I changed net_node.inl and cryptonote_config to do this.

The weirdest thing is it says "you are now synchronized with the network" if I pass --no-igd. But I still get the errors.

Comment: Are you trying to create a fork or just run a test network?

Comment: Test network!  I ultimately want an isolated node connected to a not isolated one.

Comment: See: https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet